# no uimenucontroller with uitextview showing, universal app xcode 4

Tags: iphone, ipad, xcode4, uitextview, uimenucontroller

On the simulator I see the UIMenucontroller without a problem but it won't appear testing on device running iOs 4+ .  It is a standard uitextview added using IB.

I have added these methods to the viewcontroller which is the delegate but I don't think they are necessary since I want the standard menucontroller, select, copy, etc.  Not to mention they are not being called.

thanks for the help

```
- (BOOL)canPerformAction:(SEL)action withSender:(id)sender {

    NSLog(@"Can perform action called");

    BOOL answer = NO;

    if (action == @selector(copy:))
    {
        answer = YES;
    }
    if (action == @selector(cut:))
    {
        answer = YES;     
    }
    if (action == @selector(paste:))
    {
        answer = YES;
    }
    if (action == @selector(select:))
    {
        answer = YES;
    }
   if (action == @selector(selectAll:))
    {
        answer = YES;
    }

    return answer;
}

- (BOOL) canBecomeFirstResponder {
    NSLog(@"can become first called");
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a gesture recognizer, or override the touchesEnded:withEvent: method, and display the menu controller:

```
//Assumes you assigned a CGRect for where the menu should appear to theRect
UIMenuController *mc = [UIMenuController sharedMenuController];
[mc setTargetRect:theRect inView:self];
[mc setMenuVisible:YES animated:YES];
```

You also [should override the methods](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIResponderStandardEditActions_Protocol/UIResponderStandardEditActions.html#//apple_ref/occ/cat/UIResponderStandardEditActions) -copy,-cut,-paste, etc.

Comment: this has to be done even to get the standard select, copy , paste?  I thought it was for nonstandard menu.  By the way I can see them in the simulator just not on device.

Comment: I might be mistaken - I'm away from my Mac, but now I realize that since my app uses Core Text, I probably need that code whereas yours may not. Since the docs strongly encourage overriding the standard cut/copy/paste methods, you might try that to see if it resolves the issue.

Comment: please let me know when you have a chance, i was under the impression that the standard copy / paste always showed up with a uitextview, but that is not the behavior I am seeing.